# How to start the second activity from the first, directly, not through a button?

Tags: android

All the textbooks/guides start the second activity via click a button.

I thought I can start it directly by just removing the button codes.
Obvious I was wrong. Below code reports

> Unfortunately, the xxxx has stopped

How to start the second activity from the first?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent iCodes = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(iCodes);

    }
```

Comment: What would be the point of starting an activity just to start another one? You would never see the first Activity

Comment: And can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resisted in Manifest.xml.

I found out the problem by my own:
The OtherActivity class's xml layout used main's by mistake, namely 2 activities shared same xml. Though it pass the compile.

So I solved it by use the correct xml in OtherActivity.

public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.**activity_main**);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

### Did you declare your other Activity in Manifest?

---

in `MainActivity` class:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(activityIntent);
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent aIntent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(aIntent);

 AndroidManifest.xml:

<activity
        android:name=".OtherActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.